# battery is not working

Tags: honda, battery, civic, battery-drain

I have a Honda civic 2006 automatic. Whenever I come after driving and park the car, the battery will automatically be empty in some time. I can not start the car until I get the battery charged from mechanic. Could anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 2):

Two things could be wrong.

First and most likely is the battery will no longer take a charge and needs to be replaced. A battery will usually last about five years. Once dead where it isn't taking a charge, you won't be able to do much without replacing it.

The second thing which could be wrong is the alternator may be dead. You can check this with a multi-meter. If you get a reading of around 13.1-14 volts dc, the alternator is charging just fine. If, after getting a jump start, you take a reading and it continually drops (very slowly), this would indicate the alternator is bad and needs replaced. From your description, I'm suggesting this is not the case.